# Best way to assign a variable one of two possible values based on defined?

Tags: perl

```
    my $port_string;
    if (defined($self->{port_range})) {
        $port_string = $self->{port_range};
    } else {
        $port_string = "whatever2";
    }
```

I'd like to assign a variable one value if it's defined or another value if the first is undef.

Is there a one line way to do this in Perl? Or at least simpler than what I have up there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Perl 5.10 and above, you can use the [defined-or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) operator:

```
my $port_string = $self->{port_range} // "whatever2";
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the conditional operator to make this statement more concise:

```
my $port_string = defined $self->{port_range} ? $self->{port_range} :
                                                "whatever2";
```

You can also used defined-or:

```
my $port_string = $self->{port_range} // "whatever2";
```

or logical-or:

```
my $port_string = $self->{port_range} || "whatever2";
```

defined-or is probably the *most* concise.

Note: As @ikegami mentions below, the logical-or case will do the replacement if `$self->{port_range}` is `0` or `""` because those values are *falsy*.

Comment: @ikegami A good note, probably ok in this case. Is it not called a ternary operator in Perl ?

Comment: It is *a* ternary operator. It is not *the* ternary operator. It is the conditional operator.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
my $port_string = defined $self->port_range
  ? $self->port_range
  : "whatever2";
```

should be good.